# My Macbook's headphone jack stopped working, how do I fix it?

Tags: macos, audio, headphones

my headphone jack output stopped working a couple days ago. As in - when I jack a cable (or headphones) the sound comes via the built-in speakers.

On the installed Windows (Bootcamp) it works OK (sound coming out via headphones when jacked in).

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this?

The OS is Lion, freshly updated (update after the problem first appeared).

Comment: Have you checked the Sound pref pane in System Preferences? There's a tab labeled "Output" where (I'd expect, as I don't have a portable in front of me just now) you can switch output between built-in speakers and the headphone jack. If the first toggle doesn't work, toggle it again.

Comment: So, the problem sort of went away by itself, very likely due to @bneely's comment, I messed with some settings but can't remember exactly. In any case thanks @bneely!

Answer (score 4):

(posted as an answer so you can accept it and mark this issue resolved)

Have you checked the Sound pref pane in System Preferences? There's a tab labeled "Output" where (I'd expect, as I don't have a portable in front of me just now) you can switch output between built-in speakers and the headphone jack. If the first toggle doesn't work, toggle it again.

Answer (score 2):

The question is quite old now, but issue still remains on latest macOS (former OSX) version 10.12.4 Beta (16E163f).
One day I was using the headphones and the next day headphones jack port stopped working.
Tried:

- Reboot
- Settings -> Sound -> "Use audio port for: Sound output"
- Select headphones instead of any other thing on "device for
  sound output"
- Reset NVRAM (previous PRAM)
- Reset SMC

Nothing worked, then I tried to reboot with headphones plugged in, kind of worked, but if you unplug the headphones after rebooting, and then plug back in, it's not working anymore (it's kind of a workaround).

<strike>SOLUTION</strike>:
 >> Shut Down -> Start MacBook and press `CMD+R` (Recovery Mode) -> Disk utility -> Select boot disk -> "First Aid" (both on the disk and the on the partition, did it also for the "Recover Disk Image", not sure if it helps) -> Reboot.

So far it's working fine.
Hope it solves your problem.
P.S.:What I was going to try next (not sure if it's possible) was to update/force reinstall audio drivers.

EDIT:
It stopped working, and looks like it's not possible to reinstall audio drivers)
Workaround: Without the need to reboot or anything, just: plug headphones in -> close the lid (sleep) -> open the lid (wake)
Sound should now be coming out through the headphones.